# Reduce the code length of a work hours display

Tags: php

I have written some code to retrieve the various work hours for my different restaurants from a database and display whether they are open of not right now.

The work hours are defined like this: `10:30to13:30/18:30to22:30`.

The problem is that I couldn't find a short way to write all the following code. How can I reduce its length?

```
if ($result > 0) {
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

        //SETUP HOURS FOR EACH DAY
        $timesSun = $row['sunday'];
        $timesMon = $row['monday'];
        $timesTue = $row['tuesday'];
        $timesWed = $row['wednesday'];
        $timesThu = $row['thursday'];
        $timesFri = $row['friday'];
        $timesSat = $row['saturday'];

        //SEPARATE DAY & NIGHT
        $sepDNsun = explode('/',$timesSun);
        $sepDNmon = explode('/',$timesMon);
        $sepDNtue = explode('/',$timesTue);
        $sepDNwed = explode('/',$timesWed);
        $sepDNthu = explode('/',$timesThu);
        $sepDNfri = explode('/',$timesFri);
        $sepDNsat = explode('/',$timesSat);

        //SEPARATE OPEN AND CLOSE
        $daySun = explode('to',$sepDNsun[0]);
        $nightSun = explode('to',$sepDNsun[1]);
        $dayMon = explode('to',$sepDNmon[0]);
        $nightMon = explode('to',$sepDNmon[1]);
        $dayTue = explode('to',$sepDNtue[0]);
        $nightTue = explode('to',$sepDNtue[1]);
        $dayWed = explode('to',$sepDNwed[0]);
        $nightWed = explode('to',$sepDNwed[1]);
        $dayThu = explode('to',$sepDNthu[0]);
        $nightThu = explode('to',$sepDNthu[1]);
        $dayFri = explode('to',$sepDNfri[0]);
        $nightFri = explode('to',$sepDNfri[1]);
        $daySat = explode('to',$sepDNsat[0]);
        $nightSat = explode('to',$sepDNsat[1]);

        //SET OPEN & CLOSE
        $dayOpenSun = $daySun[0];
        $dayCloseSun = $daySun[1];
        $nightOpenSun = $nightSun[0];
        $nightCloseSun = $nightSun[1];

        $dayOpenMon = $dayMon[0];
        $dayCloseMon = $dayMon[1];
        $nightOpenMon = $nightMon[0];
        $nightCloseMon = $nightMon[1];

        $dayOpenTue = $dayTue[0];
        $dayCloseTue = $dayTue[1];
        $nightOpenTue = $nightTue[0];
        $nightCloseTue = $nightTue[1];

        $dayOpenWed = $dayWed[0];
        $dayCloseWed = $dayWed[1];
        $nightOpenWed = $nightWed[0];
        $nightCloseWed = $nightWed[1];

        $dayOpenThu = $dayThu[0];
        $dayCloseThu = $dayThu[1];
        $nightOpenThu = $nightThu[0];
        $nightCloseThu = $nightThu[1];

        $dayOpenFri = $dayFri[0];
        $dayCloseFri = $dayFri[1];
        $nightOpenFri = $nightFri[0];
        $nightCloseFri = $nightFri[1];

        $dayOpenSat = $daySat[0];
        $dayCloseSat = $daySat[1];
        $nightOpenSat = $nightSat[0];
        $nightCloseSat = $nightSat[1];

        //SET STORE OPENING HOURS
        $storeSchedule = [
            'Sun' => [$dayOpenSun => $dayCloseSun, $nightOpenSun => $nightCloseSun],
            'Mon' => [$dayOpenMon => $dayCloseMon, $nightOpenMon => $nightCloseMon],
            'Tue' => [$dayOpenTue => $dayCloseTue, $nightOpenTue => $nightCloseTue],
            'Wed' => [$dayOpenWed => $dayCloseWed, $nightOpenWed => $nightCloseWed],
            'Thu' => [$dayOpenThu => $dayCloseThu, $nightOpenThu => $nightCloseThu],
            'Fri' => [$dayOpenFri => $dayCloseFri, $nightOpenFri => $nightCloseFri],
            'Sat' => [$dayOpenSat => $dayCloseSat, $nightOpenSat => $nightCloseSat]
        ];

        // current or user supplied UNIX timestamp
        $timestamp = time();

        // default status
        $status = $lang["NO-READY"];

        // get current time object
        $currentTime = (new DateTime())->setTimestamp($timestamp);

        // loop through time ranges for current day
        foreach ($storeSchedule[date('D', $timestamp)] as $startTime => $endTime) {

            // create time objects from start/end times
            $startTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('G:i', $startTime);
            $endTime   = DateTime::createFromFormat('G:i', $endTime);

            // check if current time is within a range
            if (($startTime < $currentTime) && ($currentTime < $endTime)) {
                $status = $lang["READY"];
                break;
            }
        }

        //OUTPUT CONTENT
        echo '<li>
                  <div class="rest-list-content">
                      <a href="'. $location .'/restaurants/'. $row["rest_url"] .'">
                      <img src="images/all_rest/'. $row["rest_logo"] .'" alt="'. $row["rest_name"] .'">
                      <h1>'. $row["rest_name"] .'</h1>
                      <p>Cuisine: <span>'. $row["cuisine_name"] .'</span></p>
                      <p>Minimun Order: <span>$'. $row["rest_min_order"] .'</span></p>
                      <p class="availability">'. $status .'</p>
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </li>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Preamble

I might be wrong, but looking at this code, it seems that what you are doing is showing whether the restaurants are opened right now or not.

There are quite a few things to optimize in there:

- You keep redeclaring `$timestamp = time();` and the other variables associated to it. This is rather inefficient as the time won't change much during the execution of the script. Even if the script took more than a second to run, this is really negligible. This must be declared once, before the loop.
- You process all 7 days of the week while you only need the one that corresponds to today, we can cut this workload down by 85%.
- So many unique variables. This can be reduced significantly. Arrays are our friends.

### Let's minimize

```
$currentTime = new DateTime('now');
$currentDay  = strtolower($currentTime->format('l'));

if($result > 0) {
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

        $schedule = explode('/',
            str_replace('to', '/', $row[$currentDay])
        );

        foreach($schedule as $time) {
            $schedule['time'][] = DateTime::createFromFormat('G:i', $time);
        }

        $status =
            ($schedule['time'][0] <= $currentTime && $currentTime <= $schedule['time'][1])
            ||
            ($schedule['time'][2] <= $currentTime && $currentTime <= $schedule['time'][3])
            ? $lang["READY"]
            : $lang["NO-READY"];

        /*
        HTML GOES HERE
        */
    }
}
else {
    echo '0 results';
}
```

### What happened

Since the date and time are unlikely to change during the execution of the script, we moved that part at the beginning.

- This returns a `DateTime` object for "now", no need to call `time()`:

  ```
  $currentTime = new DateTime('now');
  ```
- This returns the full textual day of today, which gets converted to lowercase to match the database records (ex: `tuesday`):

  ```
  $currentDay  = strtolower($currentTime->format('l'));
  ```
- Then for each record iterated:

  - We use `$row[$currentDay]`, which is today's data.
  - We replace `to` with `/`, this results in `xx:xx/xx:xx/xx:xx/xx:xx`.
  - We explode using `/`.

    ```
    $schedule = explode('/',
        str_replace('to', '/', $row[$currentDay])
    );
    ```
  - We now have an array containing 4 values:

    ```
    Array
    (
        [0] => 9:30
        [1] => 13:30
        [2] => 17:30
        [3] => 20:30
    )
    ```
  - We create a `DateTime` object from each of these values, that we store in that same array:

    ```
    foreach($schedule as $time) {
        $schedule['time'][] = DateTime::createFromFormat('G:i', $time);
    }
    ```
  - We now have this array:

    ```
    Array
    (
        [0] => 9:30
        [1] => 13:30
        [2] => 17:30
        [3] => 20:30
        [time] => Array
            (
                [0] => DateTime Object
                    (
                        [date] => 2015-09-29 09:30:00.000000
                        [timezone_type] => 3
                        [timezone] => Europe/Paris
                    )
                [1] => DateTime Object
                    (
                        [date] => 2015-09-29 13:30:00.000000
                        [timezone_type] => 3
                        [timezone] => Europe/Paris
                    )
                [2] => DateTime Object
                    (
                        [date] => 2015-09-29 17:30:00.000000
                        [timezone_type] => 3
                        [timezone] => Europe/Paris
                    )
                [3] => DateTime Object
                    (
                        [date] => 2015-09-29 20:30:00.000000
                        [timezone_type] => 3
                        [timezone] => Europe/Paris
                    )
            )
    )
    ```
  - We use a ternary operator to set the status (`true ? true : false`).
    This checks if "now" is either between morning hours or evening hours at the same time.

    ```
    $status =
        ($schedule['time'][0] <= $currentTime && $currentTime <= $schedule['time'][1])
        ||
        ($schedule['time'][2] <= $currentTime && $currentTime <= $schedule['time'][3])
        ? $lang["READY"]
        : $lang["NO-READY"];
    ```
  - `$status` is now available, the html can be built.
  - Repeat until there is no record left.
- We exit the loop.
- We're done.

Comment: still dont test it but if it works you will be my new hero